# Mutable array only contains identical items

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to store Json data to a mutable array. The JSON data has "city" and main dictionary branch inside a loop , where main branch contains temperature.  When I loop through the main, all the previous temperatures are replaced by the later. 
Here's the sample code :

```
object = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?q=london,uk&APPID="];
//8a7bc4e5d8246122294adb174b708711
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
Model *mod = [[Model alloc]init];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *cityDict = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"city"];
NSString *cityName = [cityDict objectForKey:@"name"];


 // NSLog(@"%@",cityName);
   NSLog(@"%@",mod.city);
NSMutableArray *arrayOfTemperature = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"list"];
for (NSDictionary *obj in arrayOfTemperature) {
    NSDictionary *main = [obj objectForKey:@"main"];
    NSString *temp = [main objectForKey:@"temp"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    mod.temp = temp;
    [object addObject:mod];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the same `mod` instance over and over. You need to create a new one each iteration.

Move the line:

```
Model *mod = [[Model alloc]init];
```

to inside the `for` loop:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfTemperature = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"list"];
for (NSDictionary *obj in arrayOfTemperature) {
    Model *mod = [[Model alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *main = [obj objectForKey:@"main"];
    NSString *temp = [main objectForKey:@"temp"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",temp);
    mod.temp = temp;
    [object addObject:mod];
}
```